# Before process_action callback :require_no_authentication has not been defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to confirm the user when the sign-up for the first time but the user keeps getting this error.As soon as he gets the email for confirmation and when he clicks on it. He gets the below error

**error.log**

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=zu1phZ8TaJHNFDJcXWvE" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-03 13:00:02 +0530
   (4.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC

ArgumentError (Before process_action callback :require_no_authentication has not been defined):

app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ConfirmationsController>'
app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

**confirmations_controller.rb**

```
class ConfirmationsController <  Devise::ConfirmationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication!
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

end
```

First I thought I don't have this **require_no_authentication!** method. So I try to place the code for this method in the controller itself still it didn't work.

```
class ConfirmationsController <  Devise::ConfirmationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication!
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  private
  def require_no_authentication!
    assert_is_devise_resource!
    return unless is_navigational_format?
    no_input = devise_mapping.no_input_strategies

    authenticated = if no_input.present?
      args = no_input.dup.push scope: resource_name
      warden.authenticate?(*args)
    else
      warden.authenticated?(resource_name)
    end

    if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
      flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
      redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
    registrations: 'api/v1/registrations',
    passwords: 'api/v1/passwords',
    :confirmations => "confirmations" 
  }
end
```

Comment: Please, post error with a few lines of stack trace

Comment: I have updated my error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I was not skipping the require_login method which I have made to check whether user has authentication_token or not

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  skip_before_action :require_login!

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity) { render :new }
    end
  end

  private

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    if signed_in?(resource_name)
      signed_in_root_path(resource)
    else
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should only be:

```
:require_no_authentication
```

and **NOT**:

```
:require_no_authentication!
```

... at least from what I just read on [Devise docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/DeviseController#require_no_authentication-instance_method)

Comment: I see... ok; let's try to debug. 1) What is your devise version? 2) Can you put the following just above `skip_before_action :require_no_authentication!`? --> `puts self.methods.grep /require_no/`, and let me know the output results

Comment: I have resolve my problem and now I am placing it as a answer